# How to track subfolders with Google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a site with Google analytics tracking. It's a Moodle site, but I don't think that matters. Let's say it's address is www.example.com

I also have a Mahara site that's been set up in a subfolder of the Moodle site. The address is www.example.com/mahara

All of this was set up before I started this job, and whoever set up the Mahara site never added analytics tracking to it.

Now I need to get analytics stats for the Mahara site. I could just add the main Moodle tracking code to the Mahara site, and use filters to seperate out the traffic, but I'd like to set up a separate profile just for Mahara so it doesn't mess with my Moodle stats.

Any suggestion on how to do this? Google won't let me create a new profile/view for a sub folder, so how do I do this?

Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

Correct, it won't let you create a new view for a subfolder.  Instead you have to create a new view and make a filter for that subfolder.

> [image]
>
> 1. select the admin tab
> 2. work down from accounts -> properties -> views
> 3. make a new view
> 4. click 'filters'
> 5. select filter type, and for source or destination,
>       select **traffic to the subdirectories**
> 6. set a filter for `/mahara/`
>
>    - for moodle
>
>      - filter type will be "exclude"
>      - destination will be "traffic to the subdirectories"
>      - expression will be "begins with"
>    - for mahara
>
>      - filter type will be "include only"
>      - destination will be "traffic to the subdirectories"
>      - expression will be "begins with"
>
> [image]

hope it helps, good luck!